# Is a there a way to display my PHP validation using the javascript code I have written

Tags: javascript, php, css, validation

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php
require_once "../connector.php";
?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c90e5c3147.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Create an Account</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <h2>Create Account</h2>
        </div>
        <form class="form" action = "register.php" method="POST" id="form" name="form">
            <div class="form-control">
                <label>Full Name</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter your full name" id="fname" name="fname">
                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                <small>Error Message</small>
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label>Email Address</label>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Please enter your email address" id="email" name="email">
                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                <small>Error Message</small>
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Please enter a password" id="pass" name="pass">
                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                <small>Error Message</small>
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label>Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Please confirm your password" id="cpass" name="cpass">
                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                <small>Error Message</small>
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" value="Create Account" name="create">
            <button id="createbtn" name="createbtn">Create Account</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;500&display=swap');

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-color: #2f3b52;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}

.container{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.header{
    background-color: #222;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
    padding: 20px 40px;
}

.header h2{
    color:#fff;
    margin: 0;
}

.form{
    padding: 30px 40px;
}

.form-control{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.form-control label{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.form-control input{
    border: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: block;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.form-control.success input{
    border-color: #2ecc71;
}

.form-control.error input{
    border-color: #e74c3c;
}

.form-control i{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 10px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.form-control.success i.fa-check-circle{
    color: #2ecc71;
    visibility: visible;
}

.form-control.error i.fa-exclamation-circle{
    color: #e74c3c;
    visibility: visible;
}

.form-control small{
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.form-control.error small{
    color: #e74c3c;
    visibility: visible;
}

.form button{
    background-color: #161d29;
    border: 2px solid #161d29;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.form button:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

const form = document.getElementById("form");
const fname = document.getElementById("fname");
const email = document.getElementById("email");
const pass = document.getElementById("pass");
const cpass = document.getElementById("cpass");

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(checkInputs() === true){
        document.getElementById("form").submit();
    };
});

function checkInputs(){
    const fnameValue = fname.value.trim();
    const emailValue = email.value.trim();
    const passValue = pass.value.trim();
    const cpassValue = cpass.value.trim();

    if(fnameValue === ""){
        setErrorFor(fname, "Name cannot be blank");
        return false;
    }else if(!isFName(fnameValue)){
        setErrorFor(fname, "Name is not valid");
        return false;
    }else{
        setSuccessFor(fname);
    }

    if(emailValue === ""){
        setErrorFor(email, "Email address cannot be blank");
        return false;
    }else if(!isEmail(emailValue)){
        setErrorFor(email, "Email address is not valid");
        return false;
    }else{
        setSuccessFor(email);
    }

    if(passValue === ""){
        setErrorFor(pass, "Password cannot be blank");
        return false;
    }else if(!isValidPassword(passValue)){
        setErrorFor(pass, "Password needs to be a  minimum of 8 characters");
        return false;
    }else{
        setSuccessFor(pass);
    }

    if(cpassValue === ""){
        setErrorFor(cpass, "Confirm password cannot be blank");
        return false;
    }else if(passValue != cpassValue){
        setErrorFor(cpass, "Passwords do not match");
        return false;
    }else{
        setSuccessFor(cpass);
    }
    return true;
}

function setErrorFor(input, message){
    const formControl = input.closest('.form-control');
    const small = formControl.querySelector('small');
    small.innerText = message;
    formControl.classList.remove('success');
    formControl.classList.add('error');
    return false;
}

function setSuccessFor(input){
    const formControl = input.closest('.form-control');
    formControl.classList.add('success');
    formControl.classList.remove('error');
}

function isFName(fname){
    return /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/.test(fname);
}

function isEmail(email){
    return /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(email);
}

function isValidPassword(pass){
    return /[^ ]{8,}/.test(pass);
}

<?php

session_start();
require_once "../connector.php";

if(isset($_POST["create"])){
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $cpass = $_POST['cpass'];

    if($fname == "" || $email == "" || $pass == "" || $cpass == ""){
        echo "Please fill in all the required fields.";
        //header("Location:createaccountform.php");
    }
    else{
        $usercheckquery = "SELECT * FROM userdetails WHERE EMAIL_ADDRESS = '$email'";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $usercheckquery);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
            echo "Email already exists. Please try another one.";
            //header("Location:createaccountform.php");
        }
        else if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$fname)){
            echo "Please enter a valid name.";
            //header("Location:createaccountform.php");    
        }
        else if(!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email)){
            echo "Please enter a valid email.";
            //header("Location:createaccountform.php");
        }
        else if(strlen($pass) < 8){
            echo "Password should have a minimum of 8 characters.";
            //header("Location:createaccountform.php");
        }
        else if($cpass != $pass){
            echo "Passwords do not match.";
            //header("Location:createaccountform.php");
        }
        else{
            $hashedpassword = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO `loginundregistration`.`userdetails`(`FULLNAME`,`EMAIL_ADDRESS`,`USERPASSWORD`) 
            VALUES ('$fname','$email','$hashedpassword')";

            $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            if($query){
                echo "Created account successfully";
                //header("Location:createaccountform.php");
            }
            else{
                echo "Error creating account. Please try again";
                //header("Location:createaccountform.php");
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

I would like the PHP validation to display to the user messages based on what I have written. If there is a way I would like to combine the HTML, CSS and javascript code I have written to display it dynamically for them, so I don't have both client and server side validation.
If it is possible based on my code I would like any help in how I can implement it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Use `AJAX` to send the form data, use PHP to validate it and, if there are errors, send back a response that indicates the errors. If there are no errors proceed as you would normally to whatever destination is suitable. Alternatively, submit the form in the regular manner and use a SESSION variable to store errors found whilst validating in PHP and redirect back to same page to display the errors